# If $x$ and $y$ are odd, prime integers, then $xy+x+y$ is not necessarily a prime number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Prove the theorems:

1) If $x$ and $y$ are odd, prime integers, then $xy+x+y$ is not necessarily a prime number.

2) If $x$ is a positive odd integer, then $x^4$ can be written in the form $8m+1$ where $m$ is an integer. Hint: $x$ can be written in the form $8i+j$ where $j$ is one of $1$, $3$, $5$ or $7$.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: 1.) just needs a counterexample, 2.) I would try expanding (2n+1)^4

Comment: There is an example for (1) with both $x$ and $y$ within the first half dozen odd primes.

Comment: The first one mod 5 can be interesting if you look at x and y both being 3 mod 5 as 3*3+3+3=15 which is zero mod 5.  Can you find 2 primes that are congruent to 3 mod 5?  Similarly, if x=2 mod 5 and y=1 mod 5 then the xy+x+y=2+2+1 which is zero mod 5 for another solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For (1), find a counterexample. You shouldn't have to look too long.

For (2), **use** the hint. Note in particular that $$x^4=(8i+j)^4=(8i)^4+4(8i)^3j+6(8i)^2j^2+4(8i)j^3+j^4.$$ You can factor an $8$ out of every term except the $j^4$ term, which lets you rewrite it in the form $$x^4=8(\text{a bunch of stuff})+j^4.$$ If you can show for each $j=1,3,5,7$ that there is some $n$ such that $j^4=8n+1$ (prove by cases), then it follows that $$x^4=8(\text{a bunch of stuff}+n)+1,$$ which has the right form.

A better approach for (2)--that completely avoids the need for a case-by-case proof--is to note that $x=2k+1$ for some integer $k$. Then $$x^4=(2k+1)^4=(2k)^4+4(2k)^3+6(2k)^2j+4(2k)+1.$$ There ends up being a factor of $8$ in each term but the last, so we can rewrite it as $$x^4=8(\text{different stuff})+1$$ right away.

Answer (score 2):

1)  All you need is a counterexample.  There is a very easy one with both $x$ and $y$ very small.

2)  The hint more or less tells you what to do.  Expand $(8i+j)^4$ and write the answer in the form $(8k +l)$ for some $k$ and $l$ (which will both be in terms of $i$ and $j$).  Now substitute in the possible values for $j$ and see what you get. 
This would be even easier if you had learnt about modular arithmetic, but I'm assuming from the phrasing of the hint that you haven't.

Comment: Thanks! For 1), that's what I did, so I was just confirming. However, this is strange... my assignment tells me this right after the question:

The Linux systems in the lab have a utility called factor that lists the prime factors of an integer, and may help you come up with a proof of this theorem.
For instance:
bowen% factor 17
17: 17
bowen% factor 63
63: 3 3 7
bowen% factor 49549349
49549349: 1601 30949

Do you see any way that could be applied to the question?

Comment: @MichaelChang From UBC by any chance? :)  I recognize the hostname.  The point of using factor is that it can instantly tell you whether a number is prime or not.  If you start with large values of $x$ and $y$ you're more likely to find a counterexample.  Above all it is encouraging you to experiment!

Answer (score 0):

Note that in (2) it is enough to take $x^2$ instead of $x^4$.

This is because in
$$
x^2
=
(2 k + 1)^2
=
4 k (k + 1) + 1
$$
then the term $k(k+1)$ is even,  so that the square is of the form $8 m + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ (1)\ \ $ Any common factor of $\rm\,x,y\,$ divides $\rm\: xy+x+y$

$\rm(2)\,\ \ mod\ 8\!:\,\ odd\,\equiv\, \pm1,\pm3\:\Rightarrow\: odd^2 \equiv 1^2, 3^2 \equiv 1$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
& \phantom{{}=} xy+x+y \\[8pt]
& =7\cdot11+7+11 \\[8pt]
& = 95 \\[8pt]
& = 5\cdot19.
\end{align}

I assumed they were distinct although that's not stated in the problem.

For distinct primes $\le13$ I find three counterexamples: The one above and $(7,11)$ and $(11,13)$.

Answer (score -1):

For number 1, I see nothing saying $x$ and $y$ need to be distinct.  In this case, the number can be rewritten as $x(x+2)$.  Finding a counterexample is a little more complicated if $x$ and $y$ must be distinct.  Since $x$ and $y$ are odd, $x+1$ and $y+1$ are even, $(x+1)(y+1)$ is divisible by 4, and $xy+x+y=(x+1)(y+1)-1\equiv 3\pmod4$.  Checking composite numbers congruent to 3 mod 4, the first counterexample I can find is

$$55=5\times11=(3+1)(13+1)-1$$